# What does this notation mean $\mathcal{H}=\Gamma(\mathbb{C} , \mathcal{L})$ (holomorphic function space)?

Tags: differential-geometry, notation

What does the $\Gamma$ notation mean in $\mathcal{H}=\Gamma(\mathbb{C} , \mathcal{L})$?

$\mathcal{H}$ is the space of holomorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathcal{L}$ is the trivial complex line bundle.

What is $\Gamma$? The context is some introduction to geometric quantization of fields using the holomorphic method.

Comment: $\uparrow$ Seen where?

Comment: $\Gamma$ usually denotes the set of [sections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_(fiber_bundle)).

Comment: Probably global sections, i.e. sections over the whole complex plane, i.e. entire functions (functions that are everywhere holomorphic)